# How to find average completion time for tickets in Ruby/SQL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

i'm new to Ruby on Rails and i'm stuck on this problem.

I have a table that stores the log for when a ticket has been assigned and finalized.
There is a row in the table for each ticket that has been assigned and finalized. They are differentiated with event codes, 4 for finalized and 0 for assigned.
A ticket can also be reopened and closed.

This is the query i ran:

```rb
TicketStatusLog
  .select( [ :id, :ticket_id, :created_at, :event_code])
  .where( user_id: 4)
  .where( "created_at >=?", Date.today.beginning_of_week )
  .where( event_code:[0,4] )
  .order( "created_at ASC" )
```

to get this:

```
id: 25, ticket_id: 103, created_at: Mon, 06 Dec 2021 09:40:51 CET +01:00, event_code: 4,
id: 26, ticket_id: 103, created_at: Mon, 06 Dec 2021 09:40:54 CET +01:00, event_code: 0,
id: 30, ticket_id: 102, created_at: Mon, 06 Dec 2021 12:49:27 CET +01:00, event_code: 4,
id: 31, ticket_id: 102, created_at: Mon, 06 Dec 2021 12:49:28 CET +01:00, event_code: 0,
id: 36, ticket_id: 104, created_at: Mon, 06 Dec 2021 13:55:23 CET +01:00, event_code: 4,
id: 37, ticket_id: 104, created_at: Mon, 06 Dec 2021 13:55:24 CET +01:00, event_code: 0,
id: 38, ticket_id: 102, created_at: Mon, 06 Dec 2021 15:22:08 CET +01:00, event_code: 4,
id: 39, ticket_id: 102, created_at: Mon, 06 Dec 2021 15:22:14 CET +01:00, event_code: 4,
id: 40, ticket_id: 102, created_at: Wed, 08 Dec 2021 09:39:04 CET +01:00, event_code: 0,
id: 42, ticket_id: 102, created_at: Wed, 08 Dec 2021 09:44:43 CET +01:00, event_code: 4,
id: 43, ticket_id: 102, created_at: Wed, 08 Dec 2021 09:45:14 CET +01:00, event_code: 0,
```

In the query i find all tickets that a user has been issued and finalized in a week and sort it by it's creation date.

What i am trying to find is the average completion time for tickets finalized in that week, but how do i do it without making a new column in the db for finalized tickets?

Any answers on how to do it in SQL or ruby is greatly appreciated

Comment: oh, yes. 
I will edit to fix this typo.

Comment: What do you want to do to tickets that were only closed (4 event) or only opened (0 event) during the week?

Comment: good question, they should be ignored since i'm only looking to find out the ones that were opened and closed that week. 
Or will that bite me in the ass down the road?

Comment: Won't bite you, per se, but changes the utility of the report since it won't capture everything.

Comment: i have had a change of heart. those that get closed during the week should be included. even though they were from last week.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be tempted to use the tickets closed during the week as the basis of the report, since they could have been opened in previous weeks and if a ticket has only been opened an average can't be computed.

I'd create a database view called `closed_tickets` that looks something like this...

```
SELECT t.id, opened_tickets.first_opened, closed_tickets.last_closed, closed_tickets.last_closed - opened_tickets.first_opened time_to_close
FROM tickets t
INNER JOIN
  ( SELECT ticket_id, max(created_at) last_closed
    WHERE event_code = 4
    GROUP BY ticket_id) closed_tickets
  ON closed_tickets.ticket_id = t.id
INNER JOIN
  ( SELECT ticket_id, min(created_at) first_opened
    WHERE event_code = 0
    GROUP BY ticket_id) opened_tickets
  ON opened_tickets.ticket_id = t.id
```

This will give you the time_to_close for each closed ticket.  From there you can aggregate away for tickets closed during the time period of your choice...

```
SELECT t.user_id, AVG(ct.time_to_close) avg_close_time
FROM tickets t
JOIN closed_tickets ct
  ON t.id = ct.ticket_id
WHERE ct.last_closed >= @some_start_date 
AND ct.last_closed <= @some_end_date
GROUP BY t.user_id
```

Note, since your tickets can be reopened and closed -- the values can change for a given period if run later.  In other words, Ticket 101 was initially closed July 1 when you ran report for the week ending July 2. But it reopened and closed on August 3.  If you run the report for the week ending July 2 afterwards -- that ticket disappears. You probably want to save the results for the report when you run it to a permanent table.